# A subscript that is closer to the tip of the nabla symbol

Tags: subscripts

With the command `\nabla_x f(x, y)`, I have
[image]

I think this is not aesthetic. Is there a way to get the subscript closer to the tip of nabla  symbol? Something looks like
[image]

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Define a new command that nudges in the subscript (when present).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Nabla}{e{_^}}{%
  \nabla
  \IfValueT{#1}{_{\!#1}}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{^{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\Nabla_{x} f(x,y)
\]

\[
\Nabla f\quad \Nabla^{2} f \quad \Nabla^{2}_{x} f
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When using both subscript and superscript, the subscript is pulled down further. Can we keep its height as in the case there is only subscript?

Comment: @Akira So to have them clashing?

Comment: It seems to me only the superscript does not move and the subscript is pulled down. It would be great if we have both of them moved so that we have a balance. I meant the position of the superscript is unchanged no matter the subscript is present or not.

Comment: @Akira That's how TeX does.

Comment: @Akira If you can use luatex, you can try `\mathscriptsmode4` (or some other value). See section 7.5.7 in the luatex manual.

Comment: @mickep I can't find `\mathscriptmode` in the luatex documentation.  Do you mean `\mathscriptcharmode` instead?  If so, what are the valid arguments, the corresponding table lists 0, 1, 2, and bizarrely 2, presumably the latter should be 3.  4 is not given as possible value.

Comment: @AndrewSwann See section 7.5.7 in [the manual](https://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/luatex.pdf).

Comment: @mickep Thanks, but it is not in that section; section 7.5.6 lists the commands I mention.  Also trying the luatex I have (which reports itself as luahbtex 1.17.0) it does not recognise the macro you give.

Comment: Yes, it is. Follow the link. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/143jL.png) is what I get in ConTeXt with luatex.

Answer (score 7):

Simply using `\!` a negative space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{\!x}^{2} f(x, y)
\]

\end{document}
```